# ASP.NET Page redirection without MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to create a web app where the user logs in, and then is redirected to another page, so everything is done in my code-behind.
I'm really new to as.net core, and even after having red a lot about this, I still can't figure out how to do this.

Sorry for this question, i'm pretty sure the answer is quite simple
Thanks !

Comment: I don't suppose `Response.Redirect("")` would work in your case, would it?

Comment: Well, thanks, that's kinda awkward, haven't been looking for something that simple.

Comment: If you like it, I'll put it in an answer, so check it later if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Response.Redirect("/Folder/SubFolder/Page")` has been around ever since classic ASP/VBScript, so I had a wild guess it would still work today. Turns out I was right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a POST to accept the login request, and this returns a `Task<IActionResult>`, then just return `Redirect(url)`.

If you create a new ASP.Net Core app with authentication etc. via the new project wizard, it has all the code there in the `AccountController` that it creates for you...